# React-Native iOS Build Failed: Error: xcodebuild process exited with code 65

Tags: react-native

I am running React-Native with the following versions:

**react-native-cli**: 1.0.0

**react-native**: 0.30.0

**npm**: 3.10.3

**node**: v6.5.0

"**react**": "~15.2.1"

When running react-native run-ios I am getting:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/*/f8app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTRootShadowView.o /Users/*/f8app/node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTRootShadowView.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
/Users/*/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: xcodebuild process exited with code 65
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/*/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:93:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
Michaels-MacBook-Pro-2:f8app *$
```

Comment: Try to open the project with the xCode, run it and see if it reports a more extended error

Comment: It says XCode does not open projects without a workspace

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command `npm dedupe`. In my case, it works like a charm without error 65 any more. It happens after xcode 10.01

command line

cd "to path of your project" 
npm dedupe